# How to hide an element from CustomAdapter based on what activity you are in?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make a game which requires you to guess a number. I let the user select how many digit number they want.

My custom adapter is built for 3 digit numbers initially, when the user selects 2 digit number, everything works fine, but the digit_3 is always 0 when app is run, I just want to hide it, how do I do it?

[See screenshot for how it looks like, I want to hide the marked part when user enters the 2 digit activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9sT.jpg)

Heres the Adapter:

```
package com.apphorizon.guessthenumber;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<List> arrayList) {
        super(context, 0, arrayList);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        List currentItem = getItem(position);

        TextView num1View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_1_view);
        num1View.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getNum1()));

        TextView num2View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_2_view);
        num2View.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getNum2()));

        TextView num3View = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_3_view);
        num3View.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getNum3()));

        TextView correctPositionView = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.correct_position_view);
        correctPositionView.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getCorrectPosition()));

        TextView wrongPositionView = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.wrong_position_view);
        wrongPositionView.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getWrongPositionCorrectNumber()));

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

And here's the List class

```
package com.apphorizon.guessthenumber;

public class List {

    private int mNum1;
    private int mNum2;
    private int mNum3;
    private int mCorrectPosition;
    private int mWrongPositionCorrectNumber;

    public List(int num1, int num2, int num3, int correctPosition, int wrongPositionCorrectNumber){
        mNum1 = num1;
        mNum2 = num2;
        mNum3 = num3;
        mCorrectPosition = correctPosition;
        mWrongPositionCorrectNumber = wrongPositionCorrectNumber;
    }

    public List(int num1, int num2, int correctPosition, int wrongPositionCorrectNumber){
        mNum1 = num1;
        mNum2 = num2;
        mCorrectPosition = correctPosition;
        mWrongPositionCorrectNumber = wrongPositionCorrectNumber;
    }

    public int getNum1(){
        return mNum1;
    }

    public int getNum2(){
        return mNum2;
    }

    public int getNum3(){
        return mNum3;
    }

    public int getCorrectPosition(){
        return mCorrectPosition;
    }

    public int getWrongPositionCorrectNumber(){
        return mWrongPositionCorrectNumber;
    }
}
```

The app is currently only customized for 2 and 3 digit numbers, yet to add more!

Comment: Is 0 allowed in any of the places?

Comment: Yes, 0 is a possible digit in the 2/3 digit number. The example itself used a 0 in other place. "01" was the correct number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the visibility of the last text view to invisible if it is a 2 digit number.

So I suggest you make the following change in your `List` class.

```
private int num1 = -1;
private int num2 = -1;
private int num3 = -1;
```

This way, if either `num1`, `num2` or `num3` is -1, you can make the respective text view invisible by this change in your adapter

```
if(currentItem.getNum1() != -1) {
    TextView num1View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_1_view);
    num1View.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getNum1()));
}
else listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_1_view).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Similarly for `num2` and `num3`.

> The app is currently only customized for 2 and 3 digit numbers, yet to add more!

By this change, you'll be able to achieve the goal of adding more as well because this will support 1 digit numbers too. If you don't want 1 digit numbers, don't apply the code above to `num1`, just to `num2` and `num3`.

Comment: Yes, that solves it! Although it also removed the green background, will need to fix it now. Thanks. Edit: Making the view GONE instead of INVISIBLE solves that too :)

Comment: Then set the visibility to `View.GONE`